What is tidyselect::all_of() passing to e.g. dplyr::select() that a standard vector is not?
"Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect 1.1.0."
I am wondering what tidyselect::all_of() is doing to the character vector that allows downstream functions like e.g. dplyr::select() to recognise that all_of() has been used. If I inspect (with class() or attributes()) the stand alone output of an all_of() call I can't find any indications.
Example:
library(dplyr) # 1.0.10
library(tidyselect) # 1.2.0

my_var <- c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")

# No Warning
iris %>%
  select(all_of(my_var))

# Triggers Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect 1.1.0.
iris %>%
  select(my_var)


Doesn't need to be different when you check the environment of the names. Probably select finds out about the locality (internal or external) with eval_select and there with env = caller_env() and when it sees an external variable calls the warning. Untested and just a guess.

It's not passing anything.  Expressions passed to select are parsed and processed (this is what powers tidyselect operators such as : and !).  Andre has the gist of it, symbols are evaluated by eval_sym() which determines their context and triggers the warning when it's not in the data environment.  all_of(my_var) is a call and is processed differently.  In fact, there's nothing specific to any_of()/all_of() when calls are processed, so you can do select(I(my_var)) and avoid triggering the warning.
